# Docker, how to copy all .ear folders?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have a following structure:

[test]:

- Dockerfile
- [Test1.ear]
- [Test2.ear]
- ...
- [TestN.ear]

I'm trying copy all ear folders to "config/apps" folder:

`COPY *.ear config/apps/`

Structure in container which is expected:

[config/apps]:

- [Test1.ear]
- [Test2.ear]
- ...
- [TestN.ear]

But in "config/apps" folder copies only the contents (.war, .jar) of .ear folders.

How to use the COPY in this case?

Comment: Do you have any .dockerignore file, also do any of the .ear files have any symlinks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `.dockerignore` to add only `Test1.ear, Test2.ear, etc` to build context, then use `COPY . config/apps` to meet your requirements:

**.dockerignore:**

```
*
!*.ear
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM alpine

COPY . config/apps
```

**Test:**

```
cake@cake:~/1$ ls
abc  Dockerfile  Test1.ear  Test2.ear

cake@cake:~/1$ docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon   5.12kB
Step 1/2 : FROM alpine
 ---> b7b28af77ffe
Step 2/2 : COPY . config/apps
 ---> 4726a5828435
Successfully built 4726a5828435
Successfully tagged abc:1

cake@cake:~/1$ docker run --rm -it abc:1 ls /config/apps
Test1.ear  Test2.ear
```